# How to connect speaker/headphone to one 3.5mm jack available on Laptop

Tags: laptop, asus-laptop, headphones, headphone-jack, 3.5mm

My laptop is Asus FX505GE. It has one 3.5mm audio jack.

Is it possible to connect my headphone's audio jack (of two jacks) to the audio port of the laptop and use the laptop's built in speaker? If I plug the green audio jack to the port then the headphone works but microphone does not work.

Do not want to use any two to one port audio jack converter.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to achieve this without an adaptor. You have a two-plug headset & a one-plug audio port.

Additionally, anything you plug into that socket will cut out the internal speakers. Some desktop computers can software-bypass this, but on many laptops it's a hardware switch.

Practically, your only way to achieve this would probably be by using a USB headset & avoid that socket altogether.

From ASUS KB - [Why the external microphone can not be used after plugged into the Notebook audio combo jack?](https://www.asus.com/uk/support/FAQ/1001623/)

> There are two kinds of Headphones/microphone connector in the market.
>
> 1. Three-conductor 3.5 mm separate microphone and Headphone.
>
> [image]
>
> 2. Four-conductor 3.5 mm headphone with microphone.
>
> [image]
>
> If you want to use the external headphone function, you can use both
>   devices.
>   But if you want to use the external microphone function,
>   the three-conductor 3.5 mm microphone will not work after plug into
>   the Notebook audio combo jack([image]).
>    Suggest to use a four-conductor 3.5 mm headphone with
>   microphone device, the microphone and headphone function can be used
>   at the same time.